# How to copy content from a source doc to a specific line/page in a new doc?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following code copies content over from a source doc to a new doc. However, it copies content to the first line of the new doc?

```
Sub S1005A_CreateOpenClose()
    Const strSOURCE As String = "C:path\to\file\Report.docx"
    Dim docNew As Document
    Dim docSource As Document
    Dim blnOpen As Boolean
    
    ' Create new document
    Set docNew = Documents.Add
    
    ' Open source document if not already open
    blnOpen = S1005B_fncTestDocumentOpen(strSOURCE)
    If blnOpen = True Then
        Set docSource = Documents(strSOURCE)
    Else
        Set docSource = Documents.Open(FileName:=strSOURCE, ReadOnly:=True)
    End If
    
    ' Copy second paragraph
    docNew.Range.formattedtext = docSource.Paragraphs(1).Range.formattedtext
    
    
    ' Close source document if necessary
    If blnOpen = False Then
        docSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
End Sub

Function S1005B_fncTestDocumentOpen(strName As String) As Boolean
    Dim docEach As Document
    Dim blnOpen As Boolean
    
    blnOpen = False
    For Each docEach In Documents
        If docEach.Name = strName Then
            blnOpen = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next docEach
    
    If blnOpen = True Then
        S1005B_fncTestDocumentOpen = True
    Else
        S1005B_fncTestDocumentOpen = False
    End If
End Function
```

Now I would like to have the following two situations:

1. the source content is copied not on the first line of the new doc, but on a subsequent line.
2. the source content is copied over to a new page

I tried to accomplish the **first** using the following code, but it doesn't work. I see the carriage return momentarily, but then the content shows on the first line.

```
docNew.Range.InsertBefore Text:="" & vbCr
docNew.Range.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
docNew.Range.formattedtext = docSource.Range.formattedtext
```

I tried to accomplish the **second** using the following code, but it doesn't work. I see a page break momentarily, but the again as the code completes, all i see is the content on the first line of the first page:

```
docNew.Range.formattedtext = docSource.Range.formattedtext
docNew.Range.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
docNew.Range.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
```

Can you please guide me where I am going wrong here.

Comment: `docNew.Range` refers to the entire document. You already have an example in your code of how to refer to a specific paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/word.range) object to control what you want:

- 1

```vb
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = docNew.Paragraphs(1).Range
    'docNew.Activate
    With rng
        .InsertParagraphAfter
        .SetRange .Paragraphs(2).Range.Start, .Paragraphs(2).Range.End
        .FormattedText = docSource.Range.FormattedText
    End With
```

**introduction:**

```vb
rem this maybe collapse the range
docNew.Range.InsertBefore Text:="" & vbCr
rem if you Collapse the range then you can't operate by it anymore.
docNew.Range.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
rem this Range object will be the docNem's range
docNew.Range.formattedtext = docSource.Range.formattedtext
```

- 2

```vb
    Dim rng As Range, endRng As Long
    Set rng = docNew.Range
'    docNew.Activate
    With rng
        endRng = .End
        .InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
        .SetRange endRng, .End
        .FormattedText = docSource.Range.FormattedText
    End With
```

**Introduction:**

```vb
rem this is also the docNew's range, not the one you want to
docNew.Range.formattedtext = docSource.Range.formattedtext
rem woo, you collapse the range again then you can't do anything by Range object 
docNew.Range.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
rem Still this is the docNew's range, not the new page's range, and maybe the range is already collapsed. So you are out of control of these.That's it!
docNew.Range.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
```